# Does removing overqualified elements really improve performance?

Tags: css, performance, web, css-selectors, csslint

I used some tools to validate my css for improving performance and i got feedback asking me to remove overqualified elements.

It does makes sense as it can improve selector performance, but was surprised to see this one as overqualified:

"div#container is overqualified, just use #container"

Does this really matter? I have lot of such occurrences in my css and was skeptical if this can do any good for improving performance.

Comment: Of course it does...for one thing it makes your CSS file smaller.

Comment: The default answer to any performance question is "measure it". You're wasting more time worrying about the theory than actually getting anything done.

Comment: In general, I find the claim that overqualified selectors cause a performance issue a bit dubious.    But,  `#container` should be unique..  do you have other tags sharing the same ID?  The "div" is completely superfluous.   Additionally, what if you change the markup from `div` to `span`, etc?

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple performance metrics to consider, but at the very least it improves the network bandwidth and speed performance by sending 3 less characters across the wire. admittedly pretty negligible, but could add up if standard across all selectors.